# React Native class component accordion into functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The following code displays an accordion but I need to make use of useContext which I understand only works with functional components and I'm having a hard time understand how to convert it into a functional component.

```
class AnnualFeeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    activeSections: [],
  };

  _renderHeader(section, index, isActive) {
    let meanValStatus = '#39D0B5';
    if (section.meanDiffVal >= 1.05) {
      meanValStatus = '#FCD561';
    } else if (section.meanDiffVal < 0.95) {
      meanValStatus = '#bbb';
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.flexRow}>
        <View style={{flex:2}}>
          <Text style={styles.h6}>{!isActive ? '+' : '-'} {section.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.flex}>
          <Text style={[styles.h6, {textAlign: 'right'}]}>{Math.round((section.titleValue) / 12, 0)} kr/mån</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.circleStatus, {backgroundColor: meanValStatus}]}></View>
       </View>
    );
  };

  _renderContent = section => {
    return (
      <View>
        {section.content.map((item, key) =>
          <View style={styles.accordionContent} key={key}>
            <View style={styles.flexRow}>
              <View style={{flex: 2}}>
                <Text style={[styles.p, {fontWeight: 'normal'}]}>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.flex}>
                <Text style={[styles.p, {fontWeight: 'normal', textAlign: 'right'}]}>{Math.round((item.value * aptPercentage) / 12, 0)} kr/mån</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  _updateSections = activeSections => {
    this.setState({ activeSections });
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.backgroundPrimary} showsVerticalScrollIndicator='false'>
        <View style={styles.backgroundSecondary}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Accordion
              sections={brfCostRows}
              activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
              renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
              renderContent={this._renderContent}
              onChange={this._updateSections}
              sectionContainerStyle={styles.accordion}
              underlayColor='transparent'
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };
};
```

To fetch data with axios I use the following in other screens but it's not working with the class component:

```
const { state, fetchUser } = useContext(UserContext);
```

And in the view:

```
<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={fetchUser} />
```

I've tried to remove the render part change the first part to the following but it's complaining about the first function _renderHeader (Unexpected token):

```
const AnnualFeeScreen = () => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all while converting, class component to functional component with hooks, you must note that, there won't be a `this` variable inside functional component. Secondly the state inside a functional component would need to be implemented using `useState hook`

```js
const AnnualFeeScreen () => {

  const [activeSections, setActiveSections] = useState([]);
  const _renderHeader(section, index, isActive) {
    let meanValStatus = '#39D0B5';
    if (section.meanDiffVal >= 1.05) {
      meanValStatus = '#FCD561';
    } else if (section.meanDiffVal < 0.95) {
      meanValStatus = '#bbb';
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.flexRow}>
        <View style={{flex:2}}>
          <Text style={styles.h6}>{!isActive ? '+' : '-'} {section.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.flex}>
          <Text style={[styles.h6, {textAlign: 'right'}]}>{Math.round((section.titleValue) / 12, 0)} kr/mån</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.circleStatus, {backgroundColor: meanValStatus}]}></View>
       </View>
    );
  };

  const _renderContent = section => {
    return (
      <View>
        {section.content.map((item, key) =>
          <View style={styles.accordionContent} key={key}>
            <View style={styles.flexRow}>
              <View style={{flex: 2}}>
                <Text style={[styles.p, {fontWeight: 'normal'}]}>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.flex}>
                <Text style={[styles.p, {fontWeight: 'normal', textAlign: 'right'}]}>{Math.round((item.value * aptPercentage) / 12, 0)} kr/mån</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const _updateSections = activeSections => {
    setActiveSections(activeSections);
  };

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.backgroundPrimary} showsVerticalScrollIndicator='false'>
        <View style={styles.backgroundSecondary}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Accordion
              sections={brfCostRows}
              activeSections={activeSections}
              renderHeader={_renderHeader}
              renderContent={_renderContent}
              onChange={_updateSections}
              sectionContainerStyle={styles.accordion}
              underlayColor='transparent'
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
};
```